What is a $T_2$ quotient?
Consider the following equivalence relation: $x\sim y$ provided $\mathcal N(x)=\mathcal N(y)$, that is, $x$ and $y$ have the same neighborhoods. It follows that the quotient of $\sim$ results in a $T_0$ space, where no pair of distinct points share the same neighborhoods. This is known as the $T_0$ or Kolmogorov quotient.
One may consider a similar process for the Hausdorff property. Naively, we might say $x\sim y$ provided $x$ and $y$ cannot be separated by neighborhoods. However, this is not an equivalence relation: consider the excluded point topology on $\{0,1,2\}$ with excluded point $0$: then $1\sim 0$ and $0\sim 2$ since the only neighborhood of $0$ is the whole space, but $1\not\sim 2$ since $1$ and $2$ are isolated.
But we may recover by instead considering the smallest equivalence relation $\sim$ containing this relation (the intersection of all equivalence classes containing this relation). For an excluded point topology, the only such equivalence relation is the trivial one relating all pairs of points. Of course, this quotients to a singleton space, which is trivially Hausdorff.

Is the quotient given by this equivalence relation always Hausdorff?
Is this equivalence class the intersection of all equivalence classes on the space such that taking the quotient results in a Hausdorff space?


I haven't worked through the details, but it appears at a quick glance that https://math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BachVanMunster.pdf may answer both questions in the affirmative.

Where did you got stuck when you tried to prove it?

@StevenClontz A counterexample to your first question is already given in Example 4.16 in the paper you cited. The quotient for the space in that example is the Sierpiński space, which is not Hausdorff.

@StevenClontz The point of that paper is that you have to perform the quotient procedure you’re suggesting inductively. Just doing it once is not enough. It also gives a negative answer to your second question, since you can verify that for the space in Example 4.16, the only Hausdorff quotient is the singleton. So the intersection of all equivalence relations giving Hausdorff quotients is not your equivalence relation, but the trivial equivalence relation (by which I mean any two elements are equivalent).

Thanks for the careful catch - I saw that section 3 talks about the equivalence relation in my second question, and that the "alternative construction" section 4 talks about my equivalence relation, but failed to read further that it needed to be iterated several times to get the actual construction.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78175/largest-hausdorff-quotient seems relevant

Example 4.16 of https://math.leidenuniv.nl/scripties/BachVanMunster.pdf demonstrates that the answer to both questions is "no" (thanks to @DavidGao for pointing me to it directly). Consider $\omega\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology generated by $\{2n\}$, $\{2n,2n+1,2n+2\}$, and $\{\infty\}\cup\omega\setminus 2n$. It follows that $2n\sim 2n+1\sim 2n+2$, but $n\not\sim \infty$. Thus the equivalence relation ends up being $\omega^2\cup\{\langle\infty,\infty\rangle\}$ and the quotient is a two-point space $\{\omega,\{\infty\}\}$. However, this space is the non-$T_2$ Sierpinski space: $\omega$ is isolated but $\{\infty\}$ is not.
Note that the quotient of the equivalence relation in my second question is always Hausdorff, which shows why the second question is also answered by "no".
Note that this paper does point out that by iterating this quotienting process, the result is eventually guaranteed to be Hausdorff and equal to the quotient given by the second equivalence relation.
