Is this relation making a space Hausdorff?
Given a topological space $X$ there are ways of introducing relations $\rho$ on it so that $X/\rho$ becomes a Hausdorff space. Here I will describe two relations which I will call inner and outer (called so, because it is kind of categorical). I know that the outer relation makes $X$ Hausdorff, but I don't know that about the inner relation. My question here is whether these 2 relations are necessarily identical.
The inner relation
We turn $X$ into a graph (undirected) by defining a pair $(a,b)\in X^2$ to be an edge iff $a$ and $b$ can not be separated by two neighbourhoods. Now we define $\rho$ to be the relation of "belonging to the same connected component". Precisely, $a\rho b$ is true iff there exists a (finite) sequence $a=x_0,\ldots,x_n=b$ such that $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ is an edge for all $k=1,\ldots,n$. Obviously, $X$ is Hausdorff iff $\rho$ is empty or iff the graph is empty.
The outer relation
We define $(a,b)\in X^2$ to be in relation $\rho$ iff for every Hausdorff space $Y$ and every continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ the equality $f(a)=f(b)$ holds.
Easy properties:
It is not hard to see some properties of these relations. These are:

The outer relation makes $X/\rho$ a Hausdorff space and its classes of equivalence are closed sets,
The inner relation is subrelation of the outer relation,
Every strict subrelation of the outer relation does not make $X/\rho$ a Hausdorff space,
If $X$ is compact and the classes of equivalence of the inner relation are closed, then the inner and outer relations are identical.

That is what I could prove on my own. But, naturally, I wished to make an inner characterization of the outer relation and this inner relation is my attempt at it. Of course, I could make the inner relation more complicated so it becomes equivalent to the outer one, but I nevertheless still wonder about this formulation.
Under what additional assumptions on the $X$ are these 2 relations identical? My bet is that if $X$ is a compact topological group then it's true. In that case there is anothoer property: the classes of equivalence are cosets of a normal subgroup. If that subgroup is closed then we have the equality between the relations. So the question becomes: Is this subgroup closed?
In general case, these 2 relations are not identical, see this question.

See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4918434/what-is-a-t-2-quotient

Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11191/nonhausdorff-dimension about repeatedly quotienting by the inner relation.
